# NodeJS pass value between asynchronous functions

Tags: node.js, callback

The most simplified version of what I need to do is the following:

> 1) Two asynchronous functions (one-after-another) within a global function.
>
> 2) Child Function1 generates a value.
>
> 3) Child Function2 can use the above value.

Here's a simplified example code:

```
someFunction = function(data) {
    async.series([

        function(callback) {
            firstFunction = function() {
                NUMBER = value;
            }
        callback();
        },

        function (callback) {
            secondFunction = function() {
                newNumber = NUMBER;
            }
        callback();
        }
    ]);
};
```

The solution can be callbacks, async, promises or whatever. I tried most of them, and neither gives me the value within the 2nd function. :/

Comment: The actual situation is far more complex than this, but it can be simplified to the above. Regardless if the functions are called :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Basics

The simplest solution is to simply pass `secondFunction` as the callback to `firstFunction`:

```
function firstFunction (callback) {
    do_something_async(callback(NUMBER){
        callback(NUMBER);
    })
}

function secondFunction (number, callback) {
    // I have number!!
}

firstFunction(function(passing_number_here){
    secondFunction(passing_number_here, function(){
        // done
    });
});
```

Note a trick used in the above. You can always massage any function to the expected prototype to be passed into any function by wrapping them in another function. Here `firstFunction` expects its callback to look like

```
function (number) {}
```

but `secondFunction` is actually

```
function (number,callback) {}
```

so we wrap `secondFunction` in an anonymous function to allow it to be passed to `firstFunction`. To wrap both functions into another higher level function you can simply do:

```
function higerLevelFunction (callback) {
    firstFunction(function(passing_number_here){
        secondFunction(passing_number_here, callback); // <-- note
    });
}
```

Note: the purpose of passing callback from `higherLevelFunction` into `secondFunction` is to allow whoever calling `higherLevelFunction` to wait for the process to finish.

Also note that the correct way to return values for asynchronous callbacks is to pass it to the callback.

### Using async.js

If you use async.js you can use `async.waterfall` to do this. The documentation states:

> Runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their results to the next in the array.

Sounds like exactly what you are asking for:

```
async.waterfall([
    firstFunction,
    secondFunction
], function () {
    // done
});
```

### Using Promises

There are lots of examples and tutorials for how to convert callbacks to promises so I'm not going to show that here. But once you have a promise passing values look a lot cleaner:

```
function firstFunction () {
    return something_returning_a_promise();
}

function secondFunction (number) {
    // I have number!!

    return another_promise;
}

firstFunction()
    .then(secondFunction)
    .then(function(){
        // done
    });
```

#### async / await

If you have functions that return Promises you can `await` them inside an `async` function:

```
async function () {
    let number = await firstFunction();
    secondFunction(number);
}
```

or even simply:

```
async function () {
    secondFunction(await firstFunction());
}
```

Comment: A god among men. Literally all of your solutions work in this situation.

Nesting functions generally worked, but my particular situation is far more complex than the example (so it gets pretty messy). Both async.waterfall and the promises solution work perfectly though.

Thanks a whole lot for your time <3

Answer (score 0):

@slebetman posted a comprehensive answer that explains all of the approaches to this situation. Read his comment above. Really.

In my case I was already using async, so I went for async.waterfall (as per his suggestion). Simplified version of the code that works:

```
someFunction = function(data) {
    async.waterfall([

        function(callback) {
            firstFunction = function() {
                NUMBER = value;
            }
        callback(null, NUMBER);
        },

        function (NUMBER, callback) {
            secondFunction = function() {
                newNumber = NUMBER;
            }
        callback(null, NUMBER);
        }
    ]);
};
```

Basically async.waterfall passes arguments to consecutive functions in the async flow. Again, thanks to @slebetman for the suggestion.